# SimpleDateFormat always throws ParseException, but Format seems to be ok

Tags: java, simpledateformat

My SimpleDateFormat looks like this:

```
Date expiryDate = null;
try {
    expiryDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")
      .parse(paramValue.trim());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And when I try to parse the following Date: "Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT",
I will receive java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT"

I tried differnt dates in the same format, maybe I'm missing something or there is something special I don't know

Comment: Seems to work okay for me

Comment: I just tried parsing `"Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT"` with `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")` and it worked fine.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does not work for me actually. Maybe an issue with Locale?

Comment: Changed Locale to `Locale.CANADA` and it works without problems. So definitely a problem with certain Locales.

Comment: FYI: it's a locale issue as suggested by Ben, I'm using US locale now, in standart envoirnment on my application GERMAN is used

Comment: Note that 'hh' in time section is 12 hour format, for 24 hr format use 'HH', so parsing 15:00:00 with 'hh' will throw parse exception

Comment: @jr593 You are completely correct that lowercase `hh` is wrong. However, unfortunately a `SimpleDateFormat` with standard settings does not throw the `ParseException` that we would expect. It’s just one example out of many of how “surprisingly" it may behave and how troublesome it is.